# Eloquent relationship with 3 table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am new to laravel. I'm stuck with laravel relationship.
I have 2 tables as follows:
`asset_category (id,name,parent_id)` here `parent_id` refrence `id` of `asset_category` table 
`asset_maintenace_category(id,name,parent_id)` here `parent_id` refrence `id` of `asset_category` table
In short I have category, their sub category and maintenance category(maintenance_category can be a part of either `category_id` or `subcategory_id`)
I have to display all categories in table like:

```
S.No|category     |sub-category|maintenace_category
----------------------------------------------------
  1.|Activity area| Arena      |clean and surfacing
  2.|Activity area| Arena      |surfacing
  3.|Activity area|            |General maintenance
```

So how I can define eloquent relationship between these table and display the result?
Please suggest

Comment: You have to make a self relationship with asset_category table and a relationship with asset_maintenance_category table

Answer (score 0):

first set your foreign keys, then try join tables something like this :

```
Parent::where('parent.id', '=', id)
        ->join('asset_category' , 'asset_category.parent_id', '=', 'parent.id')
        ->join('asset_maintenace_category', 'asset_maintenace_category.parent_id','=', 'parent.id')
        ->select('parents. ...' ,
            'asset_category. ...' ,
            'asset_maintenace_category. ...'
            )
        ->get();
```